# YDN-DB - Delete DB then recreate and load when page is loaded/reloaded but not when refreshed

Tags: ydn-db

I'm converting some IndexedDB code to use YDN-DB and need some help in converting this. This code essentially deletes the DB if the page is loaded or reloaded but not when it is refreshed.
How would I accomplish that using YDN-DB?

```
var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
var db;
window.refreshing = false;

$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.performance) { 
        if(performance.navigation.type  == 0 ) {
            // The db already exists so delete it and re-create it so we don't have stale records.
            deleteDB(); 
        } else {
            window.refreshing = true;
            open();
        }
    }
});

function deleteDB() {
    var request = indexedDB.deleteDatabase("DocsDB");
    request.onsuccess = function() {
        open();
    }
    request.onerror = function(event) {
        throw "Error in deleteDB.";
    }
}

function open() {
    var request = indexedDB.open("DocsDB");
    var upgraded = false;
    request.onupgradeneeded = function(evt) {
        upgraded = true;
        var dbnew = evt.target.result;

        dbnew.onerror = function(event) {
            console.log("IndexedDB error: " + evt.target.error.code);
        };

        var objectStore = dbnew.createObjectStore(
                 "docs", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });

        objectStore.createIndex("docname",   "DOC_NAME",   { unique: false });
        objectStore.createIndex("printdate", "PRINT_DATE", { unique: false });
    }
    request.onsuccess = function(evt) {
        db = request.result;
        if (!upgraded && !window.refreshing) {
            throw "Not upgraded";
        }
        request.result.onversionchange = function(e) {
            if (e.newVersion === null) { // An attempt is made to delete the db
                e.target.close(); // Manually close our connection to the db
            }
        };

        if(typeof db != 'undefined' && !window.refreshing) {
            // We load the store with the records here, attempting to add records via ajax doesn't work
            // looks like we'll ahve to load them via ajax before initialization?
            var store = getObjectStore(db);
            for (i=0; i<documents["Rows"].length-1;i++) {
                store.add(documents["Rows"][i]);
            }
        }
    }
    request.onerror = function() {
        throw "Error in open";
    }
}

 function getObjectStore(db, mode = 'readwrite') {
     if(typeof db != 'undefined') {
         var tx = db.transaction('docs', mode);
         return tx.objectStore('docs');
    } else {
        return null;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete a database use, `ydn.db.deleteDatabase("DocsDB")`.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do that, but is there an event, like `onsuccess` for the deletion to be able to use to call the `open()` after the db is deleted?

Comment: Ok, found the `.done()` / `.fail()` promises in the docs. was attempting to use the `.onsuccess()` / `.onerror()` Will post an example for you to use with your library.

Comment: I added the modified example to a ticket on your GitHub repository. https://github.com/yathit/ydn-db/issues/105